# Multiline TextView is wrong aligned with other controls

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I want to get this layout:

[image]

But instead I get this one:

[image]

As you see, `TextView` is aligned wrong, left side is not visible. I tried to change paddings, gravity, width, replace containers (change to `LinearLayout`), but nothing helped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/green_chat_layout_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/night_rider"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/user_date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="You Might Also Like. How to generate javadoc comments in Android Studio"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/seen"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_text"
        tools:text="16:25"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_date"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chat_message_seen"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Short text aligns right.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386844/constraint-layout-textview-overlaps-other-views-when-it-grows-in-size, it's essentially the same case as yours.

Comment: You need to create a custom layout for it . See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39830788/4168607).

Comment: @ADM, thanks! I think, you are right, but I applied two answers to my question, they are suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your parent layout width as `match_parent` and then give `textview` `match_constraint`. So your layout will be fine.Change your layout like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/green_chat_layout_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/night_rider"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/user_date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="You Might Also Like. How to generate javadoc comments in Android Studio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/seen"
        tools:text="16:25" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your layout will look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use `wrap_content`, the TextView realizes the text is too long so it separates into two lines and takes up the whole screen space. Since there're other views which are constrainted, ConstraintLayout decides to push the TextView to the left a little.

Change the `TextView` width to `0dp` and set the layout width to `match_parent`.

> Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"
>
> When a dimension is set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout